# Can Distribution Counting Sort be used to sort the birthday of student in a class?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Question true or false: Distribution Counting Sort could be used to sort the birthdays of all the grade 1 students

Answer: True, right?

Comment: You take that birthday and calculate an integer out of it and use integer sorting (counting sort). I don't know what you mean by  **distribution** though.

Comment: Why do you think the answer is true? Is there anything you don't understand about the problem or the algorithm?

Comment: replying to Arash : I did not make it up ;) I learn Distribution in algorithm class

Comment: I think it is true because we know the maximum or the range of birthday and number of students.

Comment: You can use it to sort the birthdays, but you cannot use it to sort students by their birthday. Which of the two is meant?

Comment: I think the first one... it says "to sort the birthday of all people in grade 1"